# surface plot — end points get connect connected (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, 3d, csv

It's the first time I'm asking a question here, but I've been using this side a lot on my way to get my head around Latex.

I am currently working on something which I can't seem to figure out:

I am trying to create a surface plot using the following:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ y dir=reverse]
\addplot3 [surf]
  table[x=x, y=tj, z=u, col sep=comma] {test.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

test.csv looks asf:

```
tj, eta, u
0.1,0,0
0.1,0.5,0
0.1,1,0.003870758462187926
0.1,1.5,0.4854497807832704
0.1,2,0.9801108661987092
0.1,2.5,1.475124957299665
0.1,3,1.970149515158274
0.1,3.5,2.465174424874908
0.2,0,0.003870758462187926
0.2,0.5,0.003869818783913279
0.2,1,0.007600178037527093
0.2,1.5,0.4717500879605489
0.2,2,0.9604817663685921
0.2,2.5,1.450502133168863
0.2,3,1.940596415869997
0.2,3.5,2.430695550674119
0.3,0,0.007600178037527093
0.3,0.5,0.007599272172177325
0.3,1,0.01119578499075715
0.3,1.5,0.4588344006717325
0.3,2,0.9411601182266813
0.3,2.5,1.426139117985373
0.3,3,1.911339280264065
0.3,3.5,2.396560691155029
0.4,0,0.01119578499075715
0.4,0.5,0.01119491117051046
0.4,1,0.01466455030310915
0.4,1.5,0.4466427759972159
0.4,2,0.9221820388362941
0.4,2.5,1.402047021844052
0.4,3,1.88237840802457
0.4,3.5,2.362768060123812
0.5,0,0.01466455030310915
0.5,0.5,0.01466370688804582
0.5,1,0.01801294252513384
0.5,1.5,0.4351210600735007
0.5,2,0.9035745108111283
0.5,2.5,1.378238656038002
0.5,3,1.853715860634843
0.5,3.5,2.329316824921306
```

Now, the issue that I have is that the "end point" of the first graph u wrt x gets connected with the "beginning point" of the next graph u wrt x and so on. Interesstingly enough, I used the very same chart settings for a very similar data set and there it worked perfectly. Also, if I plot the same dataset in Matlabs, I don't get this issue.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue or can point me in the right directions.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Many thx.

aPat

Comment: wow, that was quick... 

absolutely:

   mesh/ordering=x varies,
   mesh/cols=13
is what it took, thx a lot...

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad the problem is solved. I'll close this question with a link to the other one, that will help others with similar issues to find the solution.